# Effect of factor level order in cumulative link model

Tags: r, categorical-data, ordinal-data

I ran the below CLM (from the `clm()` function in the R package "`ordinal`"), my dependant categorical variable is `agg_full` and I have two categorical variables, `treatment` and `region`. The variable `region` has two levels, `AR` and `OZ`.

In a first version of the model, `AR` is the reference level for `region`. In a second model, I used `aggression_full$region <- factor(aggression_full$region,levels=c("OZ","AR"),ordered=T)` to set `OZ` as the reference level instead (`AR` is then coded as `L` in the second model summary).

My question is why are the levels of significance different in the two versions for the effect of the treatments `low_sugar` and `OA_low_sugar`? Looking at the standard errors, they are higher in the first version of the model which explains why the levels of significance are lower. The AIC are the same, so I assume that the models are identical, but the interpretation is quite different between the two versions.
The first model tells me that `low_sugar` and `OA_low_sugar` treatments effects are marginally significant, and that's the same in `OZ` (not such a powerful statement) while the second one indicates that the effect of these two treatments is highly significant in `OZ`, as in `AR` (cf non significant interaction terms).

Also, that may be related to my question, all the estimates are quite close from one model to another, but the `regionOZ` term in the first model and the `region.L` in the second model are not matching. Any thoughts?

Version with `AR` as the reference level:

```
formula: as.factor(aggression_full$agg_full) ~ treatment * region
data:    aggression_full

 link  threshold   nobs logLik   AIC      niter max.grad cond.H 
 logit equidistant 6002 -8978.41 17974.81 5(0)  1.75e-12 5.7e+02

Coefficients:
                               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
treatmentlow_sugar             -0.18561    0.09754  -1.903   0.0571 .
treatmentOA                     0.11062    0.09726   1.137   0.2554  
treatmentOA_low_sugar           0.18436    0.09715   1.898   0.0577 .
regionOZ                        0.23744    0.09844   2.412   0.0159 *
treatmentlow_sugar:regionOZ     0.01611    0.13536   0.119   0.9053  
treatmentOA:regionOZ            0.02906    0.13440   0.216   0.8288  
treatmentOA_low_sugar:regionOZ -0.01839    0.13591  -0.135   0.8924  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Threshold coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value
threshold.1 -0.32498    0.07080   -4.59
spacing      0.78295    0.01254   62.45
```

Version with `OZ` as the reference level:

```
formula: as.factor(aggression_full$agg_full) ~ treatment * region
data:    aggression_full

 link  threshold   nobs logLik   AIC      niter max.grad cond.H 
 logit equidistant 6002 -8978.41 17974.81 5(0)  4.55e-12 2.1e+02

Coefficients:
                               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
treatmentlow_sugar             -0.17756    0.06770  -2.623  0.00872 **
treatmentOA                     0.12515    0.06721   1.862  0.06260 . 
treatmentOA_low_sugar           0.17517    0.06798   2.577  0.00997 **
region.L                       -0.16790    0.06961  -2.412  0.01586 * 
treatmentlow_sugar:region.L    -0.01139    0.09571  -0.119  0.90527   
treatmentOA:region.L           -0.02055    0.09504  -0.216  0.82882   
treatmentOA_low_sugar:region.L  0.01300    0.09610   0.135  0.89238   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Threshold coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value
threshold.1 -0.44370    0.05088   -8.72
spacing      0.78295    0.01254   62.45
```